# how do i write htaccess for my seo URLS

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My URLS are like this as bellow

`URL.com/folder/post.php?123-this-is-post-title`

and i want to change/redirect them something like

```
URL.com/folder/post123.html
```

how do i setup my .htaccess file to make it possible

Comment: Your htaccess is in root folder or in a subfolder ? What's the framework you're using ?

Comment: yes it is in sub folder and is a simple PHP script not a specific framework